# Вызов хранимой процедуры выполняется но изменений в таблице не происходит

Tags: sql, node.js, oracle, express

Я создал хранимую процедуру в *Oracle*:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_new_user(
    account_name_in IN VARCHAR, name_in IN VARCHAR, password_in IN VARCHAR, role_in IN VARCHAR) AS 
BEGIN 
    insert INTO a_users (account_name, name, password, role) 
    VALUES (account_name_in, name_in, password_in, role_in)
    ;
END;
```

Теперь, пытаюсь вызвать её через *express*:

```js
app.route('/register').post((req, res) => {

    oracledb.getConnection(connAttrs, function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
          res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({
              status: 500,
              message: "Error connecting to DB",
              detailed_message: err.message
          }));
          return;
        } else {
          console.log('Connection successful')
        }

        let body = req.body;
        let sql = 'begin insert_new_user(:account_name_in, :name_in, :password_in, :role_in); end;';
        let bindVars = { account_name_in: body.accountName, name_in: body.name, password_in: body.password, role_in: body.role};
        connection.execute(sql, bindVars, function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
            res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({
              status:500,
              message: "Register error",
              detailed_message: err.message
            }));
          } else {
            res.contentType('application/json').status(200);
            res.send(JSON.stringify({
                status: 200,
                message: "Ok",
                detailed_message: result
          }));
          }
        });
    });
});
```

Ошибок нет, но запись в таблице не появляется. Проверки на `null` делал, с данными все ок.

Может я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: А где у вас  commit?

Comment: @0xdb все, спасибо, понял в чем дело)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изменения не подтверждены. По умолчанию значение свойства `oracledb.autoCommit = false`.

Оно может быть переписано в методе `execute()` след. образом:

```
connection.execute (sql, bindVars, { autoCommit: true }, function (err, result) {
```

Или метод `commit()` может быть вызван явно:

```
connection.commit(
    function(err) {
        if (err) console.error(err.message);
});
```